# how to hide Player slider in MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video app in that i use `MPMovieplayerViewcontroller`. In that i want to hide Player Slider.So user can not seek video forward or backward.

and I use

```
self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but i want play pause button and hide only seeking bar.